# Pass parameter by reference between two Forms

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

I have two forms (Form1 and Form2). On Form1 there is a 'public int i' variable, which is set to value 1 in Form1 constructor.
Then I open Form2 from Form1 with this code:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(ref i);
f2.ShowDialog();
```

The constructor of Form2 looks like this:

```
public int i;
public Form2(ref int x)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    i = x;
}
```

Then I set variable i on Form2 to value 2 and close Form2. Now I would expect the variable i on Form1 to have value 2 (because of 'ref' keyword by passing parameters), but the value is still 1. What am I doing wrong and why is ref keyword not working in my example?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's actually happening.

1. You create an object1 with a integer member named "i"
2. You pass a reference to "i" into a new object constructor.  The reference to "i" is called "x".
3. You copy the value of "x" into a variable in the second object, also called "i".
4. You exit object2's constructor.  The reference to object1.i ends here.
5. You modify object2.i (which is a copy of object1.i, but not a reference, pointer, or link).  object1.i is not modified.

There are many ways to accomplish what you want, either with events, or by passing in an object that will be shared between object1 and object2.

```
Class Form1
{
    Object i = new Object();
    ...
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Form2 f = new Form2(i);
        f.Show();
    }
}
```

This would probably be the easiest way to accomplish what you're going for.

Comment: I thought that if pass integer with ref keyword, that it is the same thing as passing object. Thanks for clearing
that up, it works now.

Comment: You could also pass a form reference/instance instead of Object i

Answer (score 6):

The "ref" modifier only makes any difference during the constructor call itself. It's only associated with that *parameter*... and after the constructor has finished, that parameter doesn't exist any more.

When you perform the assignment:

```
i = x;
```

That is just copying the *value*. It's not associating the variable `i` with `x` in any other way.

As a general rule of thumb: if you don't change the value of the parameter within the method/constructor (which you don't in your example), the `ref` modifier isn't doing anything.

You can't do what you want to do: you can't make a *field* (Form2.`i` in this case) an alias of some other variable.

Comment: I'd like to add that Form2 already exposes a public int i, so he should: remove the parameter from the constructor, set the field with f2.i = i; and after the ShowDialog() read it back with i = f2.il

Comment: I'd really hope that the real code *didn't* have a public field though... and that the class wasn't really called Form2, either :)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Martin that this type of solution would add unnecessary coupling, but if you still insist on having it tied like this, I think using a simple pointer would do the trick.

```
class Form1 {  
  public int i;
  public void doSomething(){
    Form2 f = new Form2(&i);
    f.showDialog();
  }
}
```

Then in Form2 you just work with that pointer.

```
class Form2 {
  public int *i;
  public Form2(int *r){
    InitializeComponent();
    i = r;
  }
  public void setI(int v){
    *i = v;
  }
  public int getI(){
    return *i;
  }
}
```

Remember to keep in mind memory management with all this.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to be able to set a variable in Form1 from within Form2 you could use a callback method. (i.e. pass in the address of a method that sets the Form1 variable and runs it from Form2)

Something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public delegate void FormReturn(string s);
    private string var1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frm = new Form2(ReturnFunc);
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }

    protected void ReturnFunc(string text)
    {
        var1 = text;
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1.FormReturn returnFunc;

    public Form2(Form1.FormReturn del)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        returnFunc = del;
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        returnFunc.Invoke(txtText.Text);
        Close();
    }
}
```

Major overkill though. You could just set a public property on form1.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = x;
```

This statement is copying the value of i to the value of x.  To change x you need to actually assign a value to it in the constructor. eg.

```
x=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

the `ref keyword` scope is only within the declaring method: Form2 constructor.
Once that method exits, i in form1 and i in form2 are no longer linked (specially because they are of ValueType)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your reasoning behind doing it that way but I suspect it would be a much better idea to return a value from your dialog form and use that to set the variable in the calling class. You would be adding unnecessary coupling to your forms otherwise.

Comment: How can I return value from Form2 to Form1?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers...

For now, I found three ways how to get back variable from Form2 to Form1:

- instead of normal integer, pass an object between forms
- in Form1 I could put 'private int myVariable' and property 'public int MyVariable' with get and set methods. Then I could pass my whole Form1 to Form2's constructor, where I can access Form1.MyVariable property
- pointer

Is there any other option? Which of this three options is better? (In my example I need access to only one integer in Form1 from Form2)

Thanks